# Interface with variable argument list function, by using function pointers

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am trying to use an interface of another program, where I have to use the following method:

```
void iterate_over_entries(Table* table, Func_ptr f, ... )
```

so the function is designed to call on each table entry the function f() which is user-defined.

The function pointer is defined as:

```
typedef size_t (*Func_ptr) (char* example, va_list args);
```

So that means that I have to write a function which is of type Func_ptr in order to manipulate the entries of the table?

So lets say for example I want to whatever - set all strings which have a length below a given one to be "a". Is it then, that I have to put the length into this va_list?

```
size_t my_method(char* example, va_list args) {

     int length = va_arg(args, int);

     if (strlen(example) < length) strncpy(example, "a\0", 2);

     return 1;
}
```

So If I did everything so far correct, I only need to call the function, but I have no idea how to do that.. Lets say I want that the command line input sets me the length I allow...

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv){ 

    Table* table; //this is set somehow.. 

    int length = atoi(argv[1]);

    size_t (*method)(char* example, va_list list);
    method = &my_method;

 }
```

So how do I now tell the program to call iterate_over_entries with with my_method, where the length to my input... :S

Comment: C does not support _methods_! And that looks like a bad idea. You actively inhibit type-checking by the compiler.

Comment: OH really, how do I inhibit the typechecking here?

Comment: If you don't know it, you should not use variadic functions at all. At least not write your own, use a modern compiler like gcc or clang and enable all recommended compiler warnings, including those checking arguments to standard variadic functions like `printf`. But if you prefer to keep your "I know all better" attitude, go on and hope you never work in a project with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){ 

    Table* table; //this is set somehow.. 

    int length = atoi(argv[1]);

    Func_ptr method;
    method = &my_method;
    iterate_over_entries(table, method, length);

 }
```

There's no need to assign `my_method` to another variable, you can just pass it directly.

```
    iterate_over_entries(table, my_method, length);
```

Comment: Oh is it that easy? 
Then I have a stupid question, how the hell does the compiler know I want to use length in my_method and not somewhere else??

Comment: `iterate_over_entries` uses `va_start` to get the `va_list` object that contains all the additional arguments. Then it passes that object when it calls `my_method`.